# How does one solve reverse polish notation with multiple operators?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, conditional-statements, break

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

I am trying to solve reverse polish notation in C++ using a stacks class I have created. My code works fine if there is only one operator.

```
3
5 5 +
5 5 *
5 10 * 5 +
```

These inputs would give me the results

```
10 25 50
```

As you can see, the first two are correct, but the last one only does 5 * 10. It does not add a 5 to the 50. I believe it's because I break at the end of my conditions, but if I remove them, my loop goes on infinitely. Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack stackname;
    string command;
    int temp;
    int temp2;
    int answer;
    int count;
    cin >> count;


    while (count > 0)
    {
        while (cin >> command)
        {
            if (command != "+" && command != "-" && command != "/" && command != "*")
            {
                int stringtonum = stoi(command);
                stackname.push(stringtonum);
            }
            else if (command == "+")
            {
                temp = stackname.pop();
                temp2 = stackname.pop();
                answer = temp + temp2;
                stackname.push(answer);
                break;
            }
            else if (command == "-")
            {
                temp = stackname.pop();
                temp2 = stackname.pop();
                answer = temp2 - temp;
                stackname.push(answer);
                break;
            }
            else if (command == "/")
            {
                temp = stackname.pop();
                temp2 = stackname.pop();
                answer = temp2 / temp;
                stackname.push(answer);
                break;
            }
            else if (command == "*")
            {
                temp = stackname.pop();
                temp2 = stackname.pop();
                answer = temp * temp2;
                stackname.push(answer);
                break;
            }
        }
        count = count - 1;
    }

    stackname.showStack();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The entire logical design is completely broken. Parsing RPN requires just a single loop. The shown code is trying to do something strange with two nested loops, that doesn't make any sense. Parsing RPN requires just one simple, basic loop: get the next token; if a value push it on the stack; if an operator, pop the required number of values off the stack, perform the operation; push the result on the stack. That's it, end of story. No confusing inner loops, whatsoever, are required.

Comment: what's `stack.h`? why don't use vector? And naming a stack `stackname` is strange. What's count is for?

Comment: Invest time in learning to use debugging software. It pays off very quickly.

Comment: It's required by our professor that we use one input to give the number of test cases, which is the first counter. So basically, the first input should be 3 and then I would have 3 test cases such as the ones given. That is what the first while loop is being incremented for. I realize my code may be a mess, but I don't see how I can implement a counter how my professor wants it with just a single loop @SamVarshavchik

Comment: That's information that you have neglected to include in your question; causing people to waste their time. This has nothing to do with "multiple operators". `while (cin >> command)` will keep reading input until end of file is reached. `while (cin >> command)` does not stop at the end of the line, but ***at the end of the file***. For more information, see your C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a newbie mistake to try implement everything at once, because you get swamped by debugging *everything at once*. Advice: implement loop and input as "abstract" program that call function to perform test. Leave function to be a dumb "plug"  until that wrapper becomes functional (e.g. function would just print what it had received from program). Next implement the test itself. This approach also would stop the reviewer of code to be confused by the meld of two tasks. That's one of the rules of thumb: compartmentalize your code where it isn't detrimental to its function.

Why you're using custom stack? you code may fail there as well, so test your homemade stack at first. If you were allowed to use std:: , then there is std::deque that provides stack functionality. With newer compilers there is std::stack that is a convenience wrapper for std::deque (but can use something else as container as well). You can test RPN  loop with standard stack and replace with yours after..  As for algorithm, it should emulate vintage (handheld?) calculator algorithm:

1. read token (beginning of loop)
2. if token - numerical value, push  into stack
3. if token - operation, check if stack got enough values for appropriate argument count. There might be unary operations as well (unary minus is an example), or may be even ternary?
4. If (3) failed output error state and `break`, otherwise pop values and perform operation
5. If (4) successful, push result into stack and `continue` else output error state and `break`